# How can I preserve xts format for fitted data after regression?

Tags: r, regression, xts

I did a regression on a time series data in xts format

```
> inputfit <- lm(y_t ~ y_tminus1
                   + cpi_t + cpi_tminus1 +
                     m1_t + m1_tminus1 +
                     ip_t + ip_tminus1, data = RegData)


> class(RegData)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
class(fitted(inputfit))
[1] "numeric"
```

`lm()` preserves "ts" format for fitted data but doesn't do the same for "xts" format. Why is that? How can I overcome this problem? Is there already a package available?

The other option is that I coerce the fitted data to xts but I don't know how to do that either. My fitted data looks like this

```
> head(fitted(inputfit))
Aug 2001 Sep 2001 Oct 2001 Nov 2001 Dec 2001 Jan 2002 
3.534743 3.285140 2.598543 2.271459 1.902562 1.712419
```

How can I coerce this data to an xts format?

***Edit 1:***
Here is the code to make it reproducible:

```
require("Quandl")
library("zoo")

fromDate = "2001-01-01"
toDate = "2013-12-31"

## Macroeconomic Data

CPI_Data = Quandl("FRED/CPIAUCSL", start_date = fromDate, end_date = toDate, type = "xts")
IP_Data = Quandl("FRED/INDPRO", start_date = fromDate, end_date = toDate, type = "xts")
M1_Data = Quandl("FRED/M1SL", start_date = fromDate, end_date = toDate, type = "xts")

## Yield Curve Data
# 1 month
GS1M_Data = Quandl("FRED/GS1M", start_date = fromDate, end_date = toDate, type = "xts")

# Taking the lag difference of input data
inputminus1 <- lag(GS1M_Data,1)
# Taking the log Difference of CPI_Data
LOGCPI <- (diff(log(CPI_Data), 1))
#Taking the Lag difference of log of CPI_Data
CPIminus1 <- lag(LOGCPI,1)
#Taking the log Difference of M1_Data
LOGM1  <- (diff(log(M1_Data), 1))
#Taking the Lag difference of log of M1_Data
M1minus1  <- lag(LOGM1,1)  
#Taking the log Difference of IP_Data
LOGIP  <- (diff(log(IP_Data), 1))
#Taking the Lag difference of log differenced IP_Data
IPminus1  <- lag(LOGIP,1)
#Merging all the above values along with the original input Data
RegData = merge(GS1M_Data,inputminus1,LOGCPI,CPIminus1,LOGM1,M1minus1,LOGIP,IPminus1)
#Removing NAs
RegData = RegData[complete.cases(RegData),]
colnames(RegData) <- c("y_t", "y_tminus1",
                       "cpi_t", "cpi_tminus1",
                       "m1_t", "m1_tminus1",
                       "ip_t", "ip_tminus1")
# Regression
inputfit <- lm(y_t ~ y_tminus1
               + cpi_t + cpi_tminus1 +
                 m1_t + m1_tminus1 +
                 ip_t + ip_tminus1, data = RegData)
```

Comment: Can you make this a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by adding test data? This will make it easier to test possible solutions.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick , I have added the reproducible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my tests, `fitted(inputfit)` returned the same thing (a named numeric vector) whether I ran `lm` on a `ts` object or an xts object. So I'm skeptical that a `ts` object is really being returned.

Regardless, you can convert the output of `fitted(inputfit)` back to xts using `as.xts`:

```
> head(as.xts(fitted(inputfit), dateFormat="yearmon"))
             [,1]
Aug 2001 3.534743
Sep 2001 3.285140
Oct 2001 2.598543
Nov 2001 2.271459
Dec 2001 1.902562
Jan 2002 1.712419
```

And here's an example people can run if they don't want to sign up for Quandl.

```
require(quantmod)
fromDate = "2001-01-01"
toDate = "2013-12-31"

## Macroeconomic Data
options(getSymbols.auto.assign=FALSE)
CPI_Data <- getSymbols("CPIAUCSL", from=fromDate, to=toDate, src="FRED")
IP_Data <- getSymbols("INDPRO", from=fromDate, to=toDate, src="FRED")
M1_Data <- getSymbols("M1SL", from=fromDate, to=toDate, src="FRED")
## Yield Curve Data
GS1M_Data <- getSymbols("GS1M", from=fromDate, to=toDate, src="FRED")
## Regression data
RegData <- merge(GS1M_Data, lag(GS1M_Data),
  diff(log(CPI_Data)), lag(diff(log(CPI_Data))),
  diff(log(M1_Data)), lag(diff(log(M1_Data))),
  diff(log(IP_Data)), lag(diff(log(IP_Data))))
colnames(RegData) <- c("y_t", "y_tminus1", "cpi_t", "cpi_tminus1",
                       "m1_t", "m1_tminus1", "ip_t", "ip_tminus1")
RegData <- RegData[complete.cases(RegData),]

# Regression
inputfit <- lm(y_t ~ y_tminus1 + cpi_t + cpi_tminus1 +
  m1_t + m1_tminus1 + ip_t + ip_tminus1, data = RegData)
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua! I also managed to coerce the fitted data back to xts using the same method described by you. Right now, I don't have access to the setup which had the example where ts object was being preserved. In that example the time series data was different though. I will try and experiment a bit more once I have the setup back and report my results accordingly.

Comment: I couldn't help but notice `options(getSymbols.auto.assign=FALSE)`. Only if I knew about this option earlier, I would have also posted the question with `quantmod` instead of `Quandl`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The dyn package will work with zoo objects (not xts).  Just preface `lm` with `dyn$` as shown:

```
library(dyn)

# create test data
set.seed(123)
z <- zoo(rnorm(10))

class(fitted(dyn$lm(z ~ lag(z))))
## [1] "zoo"
```